# Cannot find module '../../../../.1.1.4@is-buffer/index.js' while using "truffle serve" command

Tags: node.js, truffle

my server environment:

```
Linux 4.4.0-57-generic (ubuntu 16.04 Xenial)
node v6.9.2
npm  v3.10.9
truffle v2.1.1
```

I'm trying to set up Ethereum develop environment using truffle and ethereum-testrpc, the error comes up after the command "truffle serve". Seems the error is caused by can't find is-buffer/index.js, actually it has been installed at :
`/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.1.4@is-buffer$/index.js`  do I need to change some file to point it to the right path?

> Completed with errors on Tue Dec 27 2016 17:04:56 GMT+0800 (CST)
>   Error: Cannot find module '../../../../.1.1.4@is-buffer/index.js' from
>   '/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.0.2@core-util-is/lib'
>       at /usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.1.7@resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
>       at load (/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.1.7@resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
>       at onex (/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.1.7@resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
>       at /usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/.1.1.7@resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this error, when I node version is v7.3.0, When I change my node version to v7.2.1, this issue resolved.
So I this the Truffer depend on your node version.